# Flask: How to handle application/octet-stream

Tags: python, flask

I want to make a multiple file-upload form.I use [jQuery File Uploader](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/). My server-side code:

```
@app.route("/new/photogallery",methods=["POST"])
def newPhotoGallery():
    print request.files
```

I tried two things:

1. Submit form normally:

   When i submit my form normally,it prints:

   `ImmutableMultiDict([('post_photo_gallery', FileStorage: u'' ('application/octet-stream'))])`
2. Submit form using AJAX:

   When i submit my form using AJAX,it prints:

   `ImmutableMultiDict([])`

My first question is: Why is there a difference between AJAX request and normal request.
My second question is: How can i handle this `application/octet-stream`request in `Flask/Python`
My third question is: Is this a good way to use `application/octet-stream` ?

By the way i do not know much about `application/octet-stream`.Thank you very much.

Comment: If you're on Chrome, look at the Network tab of the developer tools and see what the two requests look like.

Comment: ------WebKitFormBoundaryxInpKfVFK8mUuqOv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="post_photo_gallery"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream lines are dont appeared on the AJAX request

Comment: This might be useful: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Flask

Comment: when i data_file = request.files.get('data_file') print this one it prints None, i changed 'data_file' with name of my input in the form :(

Comment: What does your JS config look like?

Comment: i do not set anything especially in my main.js but plugin has much options,this one is my only edited file of plugin: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/js/main.js

Comment: i prefer sending it normally instead of application/octet-stream,isn't there anyway?

Comment: for anyone else who looks for this they should refer to this link https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of the the data encoding, you should be able to get the raw data with `request.data`. 
In the case of `application/octet-stream`, you can just write `request.data` to a binary file.

[An example handler for various data types](http://blog.luisrei.com/articles/flaskrest.html):

```
from flask import json

@app.route('/messages', methods = ['POST'])
def api_message():

    if request.headers['Content-Type'] == 'text/plain':
        return "Text Message: " + request.data

    elif request.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/json':
        return "JSON Message: " + json.dumps(request.json)

    elif request.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/octet-stream':
        with open('/tmp/binary', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(request.data)
            f.close()
        return "Binary message written!"

    else:
        return "415 Unsupported Media Type ;)"
```

The typical scenario of handling form data is already documented [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/fileuploads/).

Comment: that didn't work for me when sending application/octet-stream, I get: `File "...\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\test.py", line 884, in run_wsgi_app
    app_rv = app(environ, start_response)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`

Comment: @markmnl You can use `request.stream.read` as shown in http://izmailoff.github.io/web/flask-file-streaming/

Comment: when using multipart/form-data or application/x-www-form-urlencoded to send files, flask stores the file comes in request.files as shown here https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/

Answer (score 2):

I was unable to get a request working using `application/octet-stream` type posts, but have used `multipart/form-data` type forms in the past to upload images using flask.

I have extended what I have done in the past to support multiple upload files and this has worked leveraging werkzeug's `FileStorage` objects.

The key here is setting up a post based route that is looking for a request element from a form. This should allow you to POST to the route either via a standard form or an AJAX call.

Below is a simplified example that is using a form:

**Template for the view:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery File Upload Example</title>
</head>
<body>
{% if err %}
    <h4>{{ err }}</h4>
{% endif %}

<form action="/" method=POST enctype=multipart/form-data id="fileupload">
    <input type="file" name="files" data-url="/" multiple>
    <input type=submit value=Post>
</form>

{% if files %}
{% for file in files %}
<p>Uploaded: <b>{{ file }}</b> </p>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
</body> 
</html>
```

**Flask App**

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from werkzeug import secure_filename, FileStorage
import os

# Flask functions
app = Flask(__name__) 
app.config.from_object(__name__)
DEBUG = True 
# add this so that flask doesn't swallow error messages
app.config['PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS'] = True

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def uploader():
    if request.method =='POST' and request.files.getlist('files'):
        up_file_list = []

        # Iterate the through a list of files from the form input field
        for a_file in request.files.getlist('files'):
            if a_file.filename:
                # Validate that what we have been supplied with is infact a file
                if not isinstance(a_file, FileStorage):
                    raise TypeError("storage must be a werkzeug.FileStorage")
                # Sanitise the filename
                a_file_name = secure_filename(a_file.filename)
                # Build target
                a_file_target = os.path.join('/tmp/', a_file_name)
                # Save file 
                a_file.save(a_file_target)
                up_file_list.append(a_file_name)
        # Return template
        if up_file_list:
            return render_template('uploader.html', err=None, files=up_file_list)
        else:
            return render_template('uploader.html', err='No Files Uploaded', files=None)
    else:
        return render_template('uploader.html', err=None, files=None) 


# application execution 
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app.run()
```